# Cookies are not sent with request in nginx

Tags: javascript, cookies, nginx, url-rewriting

I have problem with cookies, nginx and the backend server.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
NGINX AT PORT 70
location / {
If session cookie is not set
return 301 localhost/login.html
else
proxy_pass http://somewhere 
}
location /login.html{
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080 <- backend server with logging at localhost:8080/login.html
}
location /redirection/ {
return 301 localhost:70
}
```

so it should go to login.html and proxy the pass to logging server so that I get localhost:8080/login.html and can log in. Then it process the credentials and redirect to /redirection/ in form action (processing is done in JavaScript - it's actually for now setting cookies only). After being in redirection server should send request to itself, but now it has session cookie so it's going to http://somewhere.

But mine problem is that in login.html cookies should be set, but they aren't.
If I'm going to localhost:8080/login.html alone and try - then cookies work well. But somehow with `proxy_pass` cookies are lost.

P.S If I use two server block and /login.html and /redirection are on this second server it works well, but I can't have two server blocks in my configuration - I need to have everything on one port.

Comment: `return 301` — really bad idea. It should be 302

Answer (score 0):

Well... I did resolve this issue..
Like I said it was js script setting mine cookies. But it seems that js scripts didn't load as it went straight ahead to "/" location. what I did was:

```
location /js/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

with this everything is working.

So remember.. if Your html files on backend server contain any css/js files You need to take into account that.